# the top chern class of the holomorphic tangent bundle is the euler class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, characteristic-classes

Is the following true?

> Let X be a complex manifold of complex dimension d and let V denote its holomorphic tangent bundle (ie it's $T^{1,0} \subset T \otimes_R C$, where T is the tangent bundle of X as a smooth manifold). Is $c_d(V) = e(X) := e(T)$?

If so, do you have a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is affirmative if $X$ is compact and compactness is also necessary. A reference for the first statement can be found in the discussion after Corollary 5.1.4, the item (ii) (page 235) in the book *Complex Geometry* by Huybrechts. This is also known as the [Gauss-Bonnet-Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) and this Wikipedia Link contains a counterexample for the noncompact case.

**Edit**. I give a proof for the Gauss-Bonnet formula. I use some standard terminology: $X$ is now a smooth complex projective variety over $\mathbb C$ and we denote by $\Omega_X$ its sheaf of relative differentials. We denote sheaf cohomology by $\mathcal H^\bullet$ and singular cohomology by $H^\bullet$. Also, $\mathcal T_X$ is the tangent sheaf of $X$, $\operatorname{ch}$ is the exponential Chern character, $\operatorname{td}$ the Todd class and $\chi$ the Euler characteristic. Finally, $X^{\mathrm{an}}$ denotes the analytification of $X$, i.e. the [GAGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry)-associated complex manifold.

Write $\Omega_X^p:=\bigwedge^p\Omega_X$ for the $p$-th exterior power of $\Omega_X$. We will use the *Borel-Serre-Identity*, given in Fulton's *Intersection Theory* as Example 3.2.5. It says
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{p=0}^d (-1)^p\cdot\operatorname{ch}(\Omega_X^p)\cdot\operatorname{td}(\mathcal T_X) = c_d(\mathcal T_X). \end{equation}
Note that $d$ is the rank of $\Omega_X$ and $\Omega_X^\vee=\mathcal T_X$ by definition. As a second tool, we require the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem to conclude
\begin{equation}
\int_X \operatorname{ch}(\Omega_X^p) \cdot \operatorname{td}(\mathcal T_X)
 = \chi(X,\Omega_X^p).
\end{equation}

Finally, we require the Hodge Decomposition Theorem, which we quote from Corollaries 2.6.21 and 3.2.12 in Huybrecht's book as
\begin{equation}
H^r(X^{\mathrm{an}},\mathbb C) = \bigoplus_{p+q=r} \mathcal H^q(X,\Omega_X^p).
\end{equation}
Putting it all together, we obtain
\begin{align*}
 \int_X c_d(\mathcal T_X)
   &= \sum_{p=0}^d (-1)^p\cdot \int_X \operatorname{ch}(\Omega_X^p)\cdot\operatorname{td}(\mathcal T_X)
&& \text{by Borel-Serre}
\\ &= \sum_{p=0}^d (-1)^p \cdot \chi(X,\Omega_X^p)
&& \text{by HRR}
\\ &= \sum_{p,q} (-1)^{p+q}\cdot\operatorname{rank}(\mathcal H^q(X,\Omega_X^p)) && 
\\ &= \sum_{r=0}^d (-1)^r \cdot H^r(X^{\mathrm{an}},\mathbb C)
 && \text{by the Hodge Decomposition}
\\ &= \chi(X^{\mathrm{an}}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. The way I was attempting to do it was by using the formula $c_{top}(E \otimes C) = e(E) \cup e(E)$ for real vector bundles and the Hodge decomposition of $T \otimes \C$ but no luck. By the way, if $V$ is a complex vector bundle and $\bar{V}$ is its conjugate, is $c_k(\bar{V}) = (-1)^kc_k(V)$?

Comment: Dear @user125763: I have proved this once for nonsingular complex projective varieties using a couple of big hammers: Borel-Serre identity, Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch and Hodge Decomposition. If you want, I can show you how that works. I deal with varieties much more than with manifolds, but in the above case the two notions overlap. Concerning complex conjugation, I unfortunately do not know. This sounds like a basic fact though, if it is true. Have you checked standard literature?

Comment: Regarding conjugation: I haven't checked properly, I'll have another look at Huybrechts maybe. Regarding the proof: It would be nice if you sketched it for me (and the rest of the community) but no worries

Comment: @user125763: Not a big problem, I did this in my diplom thesis and this is (almost) a straight copy and paste from the source. Hope it is of any use to you.